# How can I start Instagram with my previously logged in account? Python, Appium

Tags: python, appium, android-uiautomator

I'm automating processes in Instagram, and I would like to bypass a block that Instagram has for this type of actions. My code contemplates the login but the problem is that by repeating it many times, the application detects it and blocks me access to it for a while.

I accept all kinds of ideas.
I am new to this. I still couldn't find anything to test.

Comment: Have you tried adding noReset to true in your desired capabilities?

Comment: Oh mate, thank you. The Appium and UiAutomator documentation is hell.